# I cannot verify if given transformation is canonical (CT)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, poisson-brackets

I'm going on a list of exercises and there's 6 days that I can't figure to this.

Prove that given transformation is canonical:

$$\Large Q=\frac{p}{mw}\sin(\frac{mwq}{P}); \qquad\Large P=p\cos(\frac{mwq}{P})$$

$Q$ is a function of $p$, $q$, $P$ and $P$ too.

How to approach this kind of problem since the $[q,p]\neq 1$?

Comment: The question will most likely be flagged as not presenting enough computational effort. However, there are rules according to which transformations may or may not be canonical (e. g. they preserve the Poisson brackets, i. e. the commutators). Apply those rules and see if they work.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will look into that.   

and sadly i know the chances are high of being flagged, actually thats why i waited almost a week before trying here, but since i tried everything i came here.

Comment: Well, you said you tried *everything*. There's only one thing to try, namely if they preserve the Poisson brackets (or you could apply Liouville's theorem, or you could check if the new Hamiltonian gives rise to the same equation of motion, or many other criteria that come down to checking the Poisson brackets).

Comment: Do you understand what is canonical transformation?

Comment: its a change of generalized coordinates that preserves phase-space area/volume

Answer (score 1):

I could give you some intermediate steps, as I suspect the purpose of the exercise is to familiarize you with Poisson Brackets.

- Absorb *mw* into *q* and *Q* to spare yourself complication. You wish to compute $\{ Q,P\}$ and check whether it is =1.
- the PBs are linear differential operators on each of their arguments, so they obey Leibniz's chain rule. So you need to compute 4 different PBs, at least one of which, $\{p,p\}$, is trivially null.
- Then show $\{p,f(q,p)\}=-\partial_q f$; it can help you with two more of the PBs. The 4th one, involving both trig functions in its arguments, also vanishes, since 
  $$
  \{ e^{iq/p},1\}=0=\{  e^{iq/p},  e^{iq/p}e^{-iq/p}\}= \{  e^{iq/p},  e^{-iq/p}\} e^{iq/p}
  .$$